# How to do a listing and justify numbers?

Tags: python

I am looking to get some help with this assignment. From the list below, I should find numbers greater than 0, the numbers are written to the file right justified in 10 spaces, with 2 spaces allowed for
the fractional portion of the value, and finally write them into a file.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
def formatted_file(file_name, nums_list):
    '''
    Test:
    >>> formatted_file('out1.txt', [1, 23.999, -9, 327.1])
    >>> show_file('out1.txt')
          1.00
         24.00
        327.10
    <BLANKLINE>
    >>> formatted_file('out1.txt',[-1, -98.6])
    >>> show_file('out1.txt')
    <BLANKLINE>
    >>> formatted_file('out1.txt',[])
    >>> show_file('out1.txt')
    <BLANKLINE>
    '''
    with open('out1.txt', 'w') as my_file:
        for x in nums_list:
            if x > 0:
                a = list()
                a.append(x)
            if len(a) > 0:
                my_file.write(f'{i:10.2f}\n')





def show_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as result_file:
        print(result_file.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose = True)
```

When I run this function, the file that I get is blank. I got it working last night in pycharm, but when I ran it to IDLE it didn't work. And now it's throwing a bunch of error in pycharm as well.

---

Thanks both for your suggestions. Unfortunately none of the methods writes the output in the file :(

The test passes in IDLE though.

Comment: how does the file look?

Comment: The fie is blank, as I am trying to write the output of the numbers list to it.

Comment: `the numbers are written to the file right justified in 10 spaces, with 2 spaces allowed for the fractional portion of the value, and finally write them into a file.`   is confusing  - - I m not the one who downvoted

Comment: No problem, no I commented to another person who thinks is funny. I didn't comment that for you. Sorry for the confusion, there's no file, really. The show_file('out1.txt') would be the command that I need to run after the code to make sure that I get the output shown below that command.

Comment: What is ```i``` here ```my_file.write(f'{i:10.2f}\n')```? Seems to me that it is undefined? You probably want to write ```a``` into the file? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This piece of code:
 a = list()
                a.append(x)
            if len(a) > 0:
Is not supposed to be there. Sorry, I was just doing some testing last night.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a string.format, you must put the value in the format function. I also do not understand what len(a) or a in particular a is used for here.
This is your function with my modification, which passed the first test (I think the other two were just for debug)

```
def formatted_file(file_name, nums_list):
    '''
    Test:
    >>> formatted_file('out2.txt', [1, 23.999, -9, 327.1])
    >>> show_file('out2.txt')
          1.00
         24.00
        327.10
    <BLANKLINE>
    '''
    with open(file_name, 'w') as my_file:
        for x in nums_list:
            if x > 0:
                my_file.write('{:10.2f}\n'.format(x))


def show_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as result_file:
        print(result_file.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose = True)
```

---

```
Trying:
    formatted_file('out2.txt', [1, 23.999, -9, 327.1])
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    show_file('out2.txt')
Expecting:
        1.00
        24.00
        327.10
    <BLANKLINE>
ok
2 items had no tests:
    __main__
    __main__.show_file
1 items passed all tests:
2 tests in __main__.formatted_file
2 tests in 3 items.
2 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: His ```f```-strings are fine ([f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings))?

Comment: @Timus Yes, right, sorry for that. Only the wrong variable. The notation ".format()" has been always more catchy for me so i changed it. Not very Pythonic, I know.

Comment: For me it's exactly the opposite, I'm so happy about the ```f```-strings :))

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions. Unfortunately none of the methods writes the output in the file :(

The test passes in IDLE though.

Comment: @CasperNe; do you have write permission on the folder you are writiing? Any errors? I did a little modifacation just a min ago and add the "file_name" in open statment arguments.